# "New favourites" indicator showing more new favourites than I have in total?

Tags: support, profile-page, bookmarks

This is more of an aesthetic thing than anything else, however, on my profile after I favourited a single question I have a notification stating I have four new favourites:

[image]

I only have this one favourite on meta.stackoverflow.com so I would have expected this number to show a "1", if anything. I am interpreting the meaning of this number correctly, aren't I? If so - something isn't working properly but this is an aesthetic issue.

Comment: yes It happened me too

Comment: 141 here for 21 favourites. Does it counts votes?

Comment: or edits? That question has 3 edits and 1 answer

Comment: It's definitely counting something it shouldn't be counting

Comment: I think the number indicates the number of changes made to your favorites since you last visited the tab

Comment: This is the first favourite I've ever marked on MSO - I use the functionality *very* rarely and I favourited that question as I intend to help with doing a bunch of retagging on StackOverflow, a site I do not normally use. I actually think it's the first question I've ever marked as a favourite...

Comment: @Flyk i mean not the changes that you made to your favorites. Changes to the favorite questions like, answers and edits.

Comment: Ah ok - I get what you mean. Surely that would still be wrong and inconsistent with how the notifications work for every other area of the site. Doesn't seem very intuitive at all

Comment: Theres no other notifications that would work anything like favourites though. What would you expect it to notify you of? Certainly 'new favourites' would be useless, why would you need a notification of your own action?

Comment: If it were to behave like every other notification it would be "number of new favourites added since you last looked at the favourites tab". That is part of my question - what exactly is this number showing, is it supposed to be showing it, and is it an issue that needs fixing or functionality that needs documenting?

Comment: Its almost certainly by-design. In this case it appears to be showing you new answers+edits. For it to show you "new favourites" would be the most inconsistent count possible - since it doesn't show you a new answer or new question count for your own answers and questions, nor your new votes or new activity.

Comment: Nice find, @Jehof - vtc'd